# Компиляция нескольких приложений на одном движке в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было компилировать сразу несколько приложений в Android Studio, которые отличались бы только названием, иконкой, естественно названием пакета и еще несколькими переменными в коде. То есть есть 1 проект, и мне хотелось бы на его основе компилировать сразу несколько приложений, чтобы для каждого отдельно не менять данные, а делать это в автоматическом режиме.

Возможно вопрос покажется абсурдным или глупым, но у меня появилась такая необходимость.

Comment: Зачем же делать поспешные выводы насчет качества приложений, и с чего вы взяли, что они будут загружены в маркет?

Comment: Ну я так, на всякий случай ))

Comment: Гуглите 'android studio gradle build flavors'

Comment: Обычно такие вопросы интересуют разработчиков вредоносного ПО=)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид возможно, но не в моем случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказывается есть один вариант через Gradle https://blog.grandcentrix.net/how-to-install-different-app-variants-on-one-android-device/

```
./gradlew build -Ddebugsuffix=.your.suffix
```

так меняется пакет приложения

Там долго обясняется, и не хотел сюда копировать.